# Python regular expressions, how to search for a word starting with uppercase?

Tags: python, regex

I'm relatively new to Python, and I just started learning regular expressions. I can't seem to figure how to find a word that starts with an uppercase. For example:

```
text = '>:{abcd|}+)_(#)_@_Mitch_(@<$)_)*zersx!)Pamela@(_+)('
m = re.match(r'(\w+) (\w+)', text)
```

I would like it to just return `('Mitch', 'Pamela')`.

1. How do I do this using `re.match()`?
2. Is it possible to do with `re.split()`?

Comment: The first line is not grammatical Python. Did you mean to have `text` be a string variable containing that... that... stuff? Also, what is your definition of a word? (because if you go by regexp's definition, it is dead easy, `r'\b([A-Z]\w*)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) with just the letter pattern (as the `\w` group will also match the `_` character).

```
>>> re.findall('[A-Z][A-Za-z]*', text)
['Mitch', 'Pamela']
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you would use `*` instead of `+` in this case?

Comment: It depends on what you constitute a word.  if `A` is not a word but `Aa` is, then you would use `+`.  Likewise with `I` (that is clearly a word, and using `+` on the second pattern will require another lower case letter for a match which will result in `I` not match).